# String variable not working - but hard-coded does... (JAVA)

Tags: java, string, hardcoded

I have following problem in Java:

**This works as it should:**

`xyz.setUserValue("ABC", "file_xyz.abc");`


**But this doesn't:**

```
String test = "file_" + VariableXYZ.toLowerCase() + ".abc";
System.out.println(test);
xyz.setUserValue("ABC", test);
```

--> output of println(test) ==> `file_xyz.abc`

The weird thing ist that it worked before but from one moment to another it doesn't.
Java bug? - Any Ideas?

Thanks beforehand!!

Comment: Can you include the error message you are seeing?

Comment: can you post the complete code which reprocudes the issue. may be having `main` method only.

Comment: How does this not work? What error or misbehaviour are you seeing?

Comment: And the `xyz.setUserValue()` code.

Comment: there is no error message...

Comment: @Hans-GeorgHaberl Include a simple example that replicates the issue. At the moment, your code cannot fail.

Comment: and it pretty much just calles setProperty(somestring, test)
--> its from lib/rt.jar so i don't have the source code...

Comment: A wild guess: are you testing somewhere that xyz.getUserValue()=="file_xyz.abc"? This kind of comparison will "work" in the first scenario, and fail in the second one (string content comparison should be done with equals(..) method)

Comment: @Eyal: no comparison - i want to set a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not a Java bug.

It is not possible to say what *actually* is causing this, but there is no chance it is a Java bug.

If you explained the context better and showed us the code for the `setUserValue` method, we could possibly come up with plausible theories.  (An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be ideal, but I strongly suspect that you won't be able to code one that reliably demonstrates the problem ....)

---

OK given this:

```
public static String setUserValue(String key, String value) { 
    String oldValue = getUserProperties().getProperty(key);
    getUserProperties().setProperty(key, value); 
    return oldValue;
}
```

... then assuming that the "properties" objects are instances of `Properties`, the most likely explanations are:

- something is causing `getUserProperties()` to return a different object in the first and second calls,
- something else is modifying the Properties object between the first and second call,
- the Properties object starts out with a different value for "ABC" than that you are expecting, or
- something else is changing the property back to its original value; e.g. by reloading the properties from the source file.

Or maybe there is an exception that you are not telling us about ... or have squashed.  Or maybe you are comparing Strings the wrong way (using `==`) and that is confusing you / your program.

Or maybe you've got a problem with the way that you build and/or deploy stuff.

Comment: the thing is i don't compare anything

Comment: FrameworkSettings.setUserValue("OWIL.IOW_FILE", "settings/iowfiles/sauxz3_" + Umgebung.toLowerCase() + ".iow"); --> not working

Comment: but i used a logfile and write the contents of "Umgebung" into it --> the contents are fine, but the property does not change

Comment: OK.  If you believe none of those explanations, I think it is up to you to provide an SSCEE.  And *"as i mentioned - it worked before"* ... IMO, that can only mean that you have changed something!

Comment: George: Another possibility of non-consistent results is a bug in a multithreaded program. Are you writing in one thread and reading from another?

Comment: Sorry I've got a problem to add the code - since I'm new I can't answer to my own question...

Comment: I don't think it's multithreaded --> problem is I'm working with an weird Framework (sadly I have to) for automated tests...
I actually am a C/C++ programmer so Java is not my strong point...

Comment: First rule of Java programming is "it is NOT a Java bug" :-)

Comment: :) yeah ok - problem is i also asked others at work, but they can't explain it either...

Comment: George: Have you tried reproducing it in one thread, that writes the property and immediately reads it?

Comment: @Eyal: should have done that sooner :) --> now i know the problem is not the set property -> with getUserValue i get the updated value...
which is REALLY WEIRD because if i hard-code it, the rest of the program works but if i use a Variable it doesn't.

Comment: @all: thanks a lot for the help & patience until now - i know now why it doesn't work!! - as I said I'm using a Framework for auto-test.. which is veery poorly made -> so what happens is that the Files i have to use are written in some kind of pseudo code so when i use a hard coded value it interprets it differently as Variable... -> thus this is a VERY WEIRD thing about that Framework...